# Convert a single list into 2 dictionary with even and odd keywords

Tags: python-3.x

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want to convert the list into a dictionary like this:

```
{ 
  Even: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10,  
  Odd: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
}
```

Comment: That should be `{ "Even": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] }` etc.

Comment: I dont think you have the variables `Even` and `Odd` defined, so the above code will not work. You should wrap `Even` and `Odd` into quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
even = []
odd = []
for i in num_list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even.append(i)
    else:
        odd.append(i)

num_dict = {"even": even, "odd": odd}
```

The modulus % is the best tool to get even and odd numbers. It checks the remainder after dividing the number on the left by the number on the right.

Comment: No explanation how the code works, and not really readable formatting == -1 (you put a space after each comma, an spaces around operators)

Comment: Added a better definition and reformatted my code a bit. I was on mobile earlier which is why

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary with two empty lists as values, then loop over the list items, and add the even numbers to the even list and the odd to the odd list. To find out if a number is even or odd, you can use the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-68). Code :

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
d = {"even": [], "odd": []}

for number in l:
    if number % 2 == 0: # even number as it is diviseable by 2 without a rest
        d["even"].append(number) # add the number to the list of even numbers
    else: # odd number
        d["odd"].append(number) # add the number to the list of odd numbers

print(d)
```

Output:

```py
{'even': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], 'odd': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension:

```py
>>> sample = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> even_odd = {
    "Even": [i for i in sample if i % 2 == 0],
    "Odd": [i for i in sample if i % 2 == 1]
    }
>>> even_odd
{'Even': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], 'Odd': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]}
```

Again, using the modulus (`%`) operator. Each list comprehension statement iterates through `sample` and checks the result of the `i % 2` operation. For evens, only values of `i` where the operation equals `0` are added; for odds, only values of `i` where the operation equals `1` are added.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is your iterating over the same list twice, which is fine for small lists, but isn't desired in significantly larger lists. The plus size is that it is more explicit and easier to read than the other solutions